# Extra classpath directory when executing JAR file

Tags: java, jar

I'm executing 3rd part JAR file, but need to add extra directory to Java  classpath, so that the Java application I'm executing is able to find and load my own class.

It **doesn't work** when I do like the following

`java -cp 'path/to/my/class' -jar /usr/local/Cellar/ThirdParty.jar custom-command MyClass -some-more-args`

But **works** with the following

`java -cp '/usr/local/Cellar/ThirdParty.jar:path/to/my/class' xxx.company.ThirdPartyMainClass custom-command MyClass -some-more-args`

Is it so that when using -jar option class path are ignored? Or what's the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dave_thompson_085 pointed out -classpath option doesn't take effect when -jar option is used. From documentation:

> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user
>   classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.